# How to get the optimal arrangement minimizing depth and maximizing level usage for a dependency tree graph?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, graphs-and-networks

Given a graph like as follows:

```
graph=Graph[{"Model14", "Model2", "Model5", "Model1", "Model8", "Model11", 
"Model9", "Model3", "Model10", "Model6", "Model13", "Model7", 
"Model4", "Model12"}, {"Model14" -> "Model2", "Model14" -> "Model5", 
 "Model5" -> "Model1", "Model1" -> "Model8", "Model8" -> "Model11", 
 "Model1" -> "Model9", "Model9" -> "Model3", "Model8" -> "Model6", 
 "Model8" -> "Model13", "Model14" -> "Model7", "Model7" -> "Model4", 
 "Model14" -> "Model12", "Model7" -> "Model12"}];
```

[image]

Is there a built-in function to create an optimal arrangement for this graph? Such that only a maximum of 2 models appear on a single level while producing the minimum possible depth? Basically preparing the optimal execution plan for running the models since some models can't be run before others have run and there are a maximum of 2 machines that can carry out executions in parallel.